# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 script - How to set local variables to a result from a select statement

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm a little confused on how (if it's at all possible) allow you to set a local variable from a result of an SQL return statement. I know the SQL statement should only return one value, because currently I'm just testing my database with various inputs and the type it should return is an integer. I know in PL/SQL, I would just essentially do this: 
select buildID into locvar
from loc
where...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a stored procedure with the return statement in it, you can execute the stored procedure like so to get the return code into a local variable

```
Declare localvariable int

Execute localvariable = [database].[dbo].[storedprocedure]
```

Whatever the return statement in the sproc returns should populate into the variable. I have never tried it in a statement block, not sure if it is possible. A few minutes of research didn't turn anything up. If nobody else comes in with an answer, I will do more research tomorrow.

Edited to ask, are you just trying to learn how to set a variable? There are many ways. Very similar to the example you gave, you just don't really use return in that instance.

Comment: Not necessarily how to set a variable but how store information from a select statement so it may be used in another select statement. I have these two tables that are dependent on one another; One has a primary key and the other uses that p key as a f key to define that row to something specific (ie. product type). 

I'm confident your recom. of using strd procr would work but I want to avoid using stored procedures for the time being since I'm generating a test script and wouldn't want to create unnecessary procedures. Could I do select statement within the values of an insert statement?

Comment: Can I suggest then that you edit your question to say that? It will be more helpful for people looking for this answer int he future.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just figured it out. It turns the way I tried doing previously which was

DECLARE @test int;

SELECT @test=[buildingId]
FROM Location
WHERE postalCode='M6N 1K5';

actually was the correct syntax, it was my conversion to a varchar that was causing an issue.
Anyways, thanks for the help Sean I hope my answer benefits you as it benefited me.